# Как вывести содержимое приоритетной очереди вместо ссылок

Tags: java, алгоритм, методы, очередь

У меня есть метод *printQueue*, который должен выводить содержимое приоритетной очереди. Сам список содержит объекты, которые я добавляю через *addUsers*. В выводе я получаю только ссылки на эти объекты. Пробовал выводить так же через *poll()* и *Iterator*. Все эти способы дают лишь ссылки

```
public class ServerRequestQueue {
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    static Queue<User> clientRequestPriority = new PriorityQueue<>(new ComparatorForQueue());

    public static void addUser() {
        for (int i = 1; i < rnd.nextInt(20); i ++)
        clientRequestPriority.add(new User("User" + rnd.nextInt(1000), i));
    }

    public static void printQueue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < clientRequestPriority.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(clientRequestPriority.toArray()[i].);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но я догадался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class User {
  ...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, работает. Оказалось не так и сложно. Спасибо

Comment: Вот еще вопрос появился. Список пользователей выводит, но и еще должен был выводится i из этой строки(Который тоже является параметром User) `clientRequestPriority.add(new User("User" + rnd.nextInt(1000), i));` Или тут уже мой способ вывода неверный ?

Comment: @Tokamo `return this.name + " " + Iteger.toString(i);`

Comment: Да, все верно. Еще раз большое спасибо